# Where are eosinophils and basophils phagocytic?

Tags: human-biology, immunology

It seems known that neutrophils circulate and are phagocytic within the blood stream, but I'm having trouble finding similar conconclusions about where eosinophils and basophils are phagocytic which are less common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eosinophils and basophils are broadly referred to as non-professional phagocytes, in that they *can* use phagocytosis, but don't primarily function like this. Rather, they tend to de-granulate to kill their targets. They lack the abundance of receptor complexes for efficient phagocytosis that professional phagocytes like monocytes and neutrophils express, like opsonin receptors.

There's some data to suggest that macrophages control non-professional phagocytes like epithelial and endothelial cells ([ref](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/ajt.14299)), but it's a bit of a jump to generalize that to eosinophils and basophils.

My intuition is that these specialized types of cells uptake debris and extracellular antigen, since they do partake in non-professional class-II antigen presentation, rather than larger bodies or microorganisms like macrophages uptake.

Answer (score 2):

Also to add to this - lets not forget that these cells can function differently in circulation, compared to when they enter in tissue. They look morphologically different, and often one can see phagocytic vacuoles present in the cytoplasms..meaning they probably do participate in some minor "cleaning up" , but like the above poster mentioned, primarily they release granules into the environment wherever they detect damage, or antibody reactions.